# How does the ~[] construction work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, brackets, tilde

I've come across a working JavaScript code that I can't explain.
For example:

- `+[]===0`
- `-[]===0`
- `~[]===-1`
- `~-~[]===-2`
- `~-~-~-~-~[]===-5`
- `~-~-~-~-~[]+~[]===-6`
- `~+~[]===0`
- `~+~+~[]===-1`
- `~+~+~+~[]===0`

Can you explain the logic of these expressions?

Comment: I think I would flip the desk if i came across some code like that.

Comment: the answer is: `+[NaN]==!!!!0&&+[{}]+~~[[]]-[]`

Comment: If i saw that in any codebase i'd ask the original developer to rewrite it. It's awfully bad practice!!!

Comment: These are the swords of JavaScript. Use them to great justice.

Answer (score 11):

`[]` is an empty array object, so:

+[]: force empty array to be positive integer, aka 0, which is === to 0
-[]: force empty array to be negative integer, aka 0, which is === to 0
~[]: bitwise NOT empty array, which evaluates to -1, which is === to -1
~-~[]: bitwise NOT of negated NOTted empty array: `~-(-1) -> ~1 -> -2`

etc...

Comment: should be: `~1 -> -2` on the last string

Comment: -1 `+[]: force empty array to be positive integer, aka 0, which is === to 0` doesn't explain why it happens. It just restates the result. Obviously if `+[] === 0`, then `+[]` must have been converted to `0`. The question asks to explain the logic.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `+` or `-` operator on anything, it calls `Number` on it. `Number([])` returns `0`, so you get your first two answers.

The `~` operator is bitwise NOT. Basically it inverses all the bits in a number, which changes `0` to `-1`. More on bitwise operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

The rest are just combinations of those cases. You can pretty much combine those things to make any number you want.

Comment: Got it. I missed the casting of `[]` to `0` part.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just restating the result you demonstrated in the question, I'll try to give a description of *why* you get that result.

**Explanation**

Taking only the first example (because the rest will do something similar), we can follow the specification to see what happens.

From [11.4.6 Unary + Operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6), we can see that a `ToNumber` conversion takes place.

> Return ToNumber(GetValue(expr)).

From [9.3 ToNumber](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) we see that if given an Object (like your Array), a `ToPrimitive` conversion takes place followed by another attempt at `ToNumber`.

> **Object**
>
> Apply the following steps:
>
> 1. Let primValue be ToPrimitive(input argument, hint Number).
> 2. Return ToNumber(primValue).

From [9.1 To Primitive](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1), if `ToPrimitive` gets an Object, we can see that its `[[DefaultValue]]` is fetched:

> **Object**
>
> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. The behaviour of the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification for all native ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.

From [8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]] (hint)](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.8), what will ultimately happen will be that `toString()` will be called on the Array, and returned. This string gets sent to the recursive `ToNumber` as described above.

So what happens when `ToNumber` conversion is done on a String? Well it is described in [9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1), and is a bit lengthy. Simpler is to just do the conversion directly, and see what happens:

```
Number("");     // result is 0 on an empty string
Number("    "); // result is 0 on a string with only whitespace
Number("123");  // result is 123 on a numeric string
Number(" 123 ");// result is 123 on a numeric string with leading & trailing spaces
Number("abc");  // result is NaN (not a number) on non-numeric strings
```

So the question is, what string do we get back from our Array. Again, this is easy to simply test.

```
[].toString();  // result is "" (empty string)
```

Since the result is an empty string, and a `ToNumber` conversion of an empty string is `0` as shown above, that would mean we are comparing `0 === 0`.

It would be the same as if we did:

```
Number( [].toString() ) === 0; // true
```

Or to draw it out a bit more:

```
var x = [];
x = x.toString();  // ""
x = Number( x );   // 0
x === 0;  // true
```

---

**More `toString` results.**

To show more `toString` conversions of Arrays, consider the following:

```
[1].toString();            // "1"
[1,2,3].toString();        // "1,2,3"
["a",1,"b",2].toString();  // "a,1,b,2"
```

So to do a `ToNumber` conversion on the above Arrays, the first would give us a number, and the last two would result in `NaN`.

```
Number([1]);            // 1
Number([1,2,3]);        // NaN
Number(["a",1,"b",2]);  // NaN
```

---

**Some proof**

To provide further proof that this `toString()` conversion happens before the `ToNumber` conversion, we can actually modify `Array.prototype.toString` to provide a different result, and any `ToNumber` conversions will use that modified result.

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    var n = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
        n += this[i];
    }
    return n;
};
```

Here I've replaced the `toString` on `Array.prototype` with a function that sums the Array. Obviously you don't want to do this, but we can show how we will now get a different result.

```
Number([1,2,3]);   // 6
+[1,2,3];          // 6
```

So now you can see that the `ToNumber` conversion of our Array that would previously have resulted in `NaN` is now resulting in the sum of the items in the Array.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do my best:

`[]===0` is of course false because `[]` is not exactly equal to 0.  However, `[]==0` is true because an implicit cast exists.

`+` and `-[]` work because the plus or minus casts `[]` to a real number.

`~0` (the bitwise inverse of 0) is -1.  Thus `~[]===-1` works.

The others work just by subtracting or adding -1 a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, but adding to an array (as in, adding a value to an array rather than adding a value into an array) casts it to a number. The rest is just using basic +, - operators (the tilde (~) is a bitwise NOT) to modify the number and then an equation.

```
So [] == array ([]);
[] + 1 == number (0);
+[]===0 (true)
```

Comment: actually it cast it to a string, not a number. `[1] + 1 = "11"` so `+[] = 0` because it's like doing `+""`